# Is it possible to define custom JSP tag without web.xml

Tags: jsp, web.xml, custom-tags

I have a Servlet 3.0 project where `web.xml` does not exist. Just realized `web.xml` will needed to refer the TLD.

From [Oracle custom JSP tag help page:](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/taglib/quickstart.html)

> 4  Reference the TLD in the Web application deployment descriptor (web.xml).

Is `web.xml` the only way to go?

Comment: You could try using a JSP "tag file"  or a custom EL function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to reference the TLD in your web.xml file.

Tag Library Descriptor (TLD) files are discovered automatically in JAR files in WEB-INF/lib and within the WEB-INF directory itself.

See the JSP specifications for more information.